# OpenCV での表の取り込みで罫線が見えなくなってしまう

Tags: python, opencv

下記の表をOpenCVで取り込もうとしています。

```
import cv2
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dst = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, None, 3)
cv2.imshow('',dst)
```

とすると罫線が見えなくなってしまい `cv2.HoughlinesP` でまともに表示されません。
罫線の色が薄いからなのかもしれません。
どのようにすれば罫線の取り込みができるでしょうか？

[image: 表]

Comment: 参考になるか分かりませんが、この辺の記事が類似の話題を扱っているようです。[A table detection, cell recognition and text extraction algorithm to convert tables in images to excel files](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-table-detection-cell-recognition-and-text-extraction-algorithm-to-convert-tables-to-excel-files-902edcf289ec), [Detect table with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33452222/9014308), [Bad character recognition with Pytesseract OCR for images with table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59032322/9014308)

Comment: Cannyの第２引数と第３引数(質問のプログラムで 50,150 になっている部分）を調整すると良くなるかもしれません。（これらの引数は、エッヂかどうかを判断する閾値です）